# I can't figure out how to find the Euclidean distance within a single dataframe

Tags: r, distance, euclidean-distance

Here is the data I am working with:

```
  rdata <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y=c(10, 12, 15, 19, 24))
  ext <- rdist::rdist(rdata)
  View(ext)
```

When I run this code, I receive the following table: 
[image]

As you can see from my markings, the correct Euclidean Distance is calculated in a diagonal form, but there is a lot of extraneous data also presented in the table. What can I do to make the correct distances go into a single column? I want the distances between (1, 10) and (2, 12), (2, 12) and (3, 15) and so on,
Thanks in advance

Comment: So you only want the distances between adjacent nodes?

Comment: Where does `rdist` come from?

Comment: You have 5 pairs of points and `ridst` found the distance between every combination for a total of 25 distances (10 are unique).  Which distances are you interested in?

Comment: I want the distances between (1, 10) and (2, 12), (2, 12) and (3, 15) and so on

Answer (score 2):

The matrix you get is giving you the distance between all pairs of rows. It seems like you just want the distance between one row and the next row? I would recommend calculating it directly, that way you don't bother calculating the unneeded pairs. On data of any substantial size, this will make a big difference in speed and memory.

```
n = nrow(rdata)
result = sqrt(rowSums((rdata[-1, ] - rdata[-n, ])^2))
result
#        2        3        4        5 
# 2.236068 3.162278 4.123106 5.099020
```

Comment: How would I export "result" to a data frame

Comment: wrap it in `data.frame()`. `data.frame(result)` gives the result in a data frame. `as.data.frame(result)` also works.

Comment: If you want to put it in your original data frame, you'll need to decide how to line things up - you have `n` rows in the original data and `n - 1` distances, so you'd need to tack on a `NA` value or something either at the beginning or the end. Something like `rdata$distance = c(result, NA)` would stick an `NA` at the end and add it to your original data.

Comment: Sorry, last question. inside the equation, where you have rdata[-1,] and rdata[-n,], what do these represent and what does -1 and -n represent?

Comment: Try it and see! Type `rdata[-1, ]` and `rdata[-n, ]` into your console, see what the result is. Play a little, what are `rdata[-2, ]`, and `rdata[-(1:2), ]`? I bet you can figure it out.

Comment: So I think the value of n in rdata[-n,] for my particular data set is 2, but it is yielding a 1x1 table with incorrect values. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: The value of `n` is the number of rows of data. I started with `n = nrow(rdata)`. Negative indices omit rows. `rdata[-1, ]` omits the first row of data. `rdata[-n, ]` omits the `n`th row(s) of data. Since I set `n = nrow(rdata)`, `rdata[-n, ]` is all but the last row of data. Sticking these two subsets together staggers the data, getting rows 2:n next to rows 1:(n-1), that is each row is next to the row adjacent to it.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting it. However, if my desired x and y values are in a table by themselves, how would I adjust the formula accordingly?

Comment: `sqrt((x[-1] - x[-n])^2 + (y[-1] - y[-n])^2)`. Where `n = length(x)` and `y` better have the same length. (This assumes they are just vectors, not data frames. Replace `x` with `x_table$x_column` and `y` with `y_table$y_column` if they are in data frames.)